# Rendering HTML in a div from an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm populating a div "Results" with content derived from an AJAX call.  What I'm seeing though is raw html text being printed on the page inside that div.  How can I get it to actually render?

View:

```
  <div id="Data">
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.ID, new SelectList(Model.Stuff, "ID", "Name"), "Choose", 
  new { id = "selector" })
    @*more dropdown lists*@
    <input name="SubmitButton" type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
</div>

 <div id="Results">
    @Html.DisplayTextFor(x => x.Sum)
</div>

  <script>
      $(function () {
        $("#Submit").click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/home/Update',
                type: "POST",
                //dataType: "JSON",
                data: { 
                         myvar: $("#selector option:selected").text() 
                      },
                success: function (data) 
                {
                    $("#Results").text(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) 
                {
                   
                }
            });
        });
      });
   </script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Update(Model ViewModel, FormCollection collection, string myvar)
{
    var q = myvar;
    //more processing

    ViewModel.Sum = "NewValue";
    return View(ViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Did you try, `$("#Results").html(data)` ?

Comment: I think you need to use $("#Results").html

Comment: Those work!    btw for myvar if I wanted to return the index of the value within the dropdown and the not the value itself, how would I do that?

Comment: Then you need this `$("#selector option:selected").index() ` @John

Comment: $("#selector").val()   This works too right?